# Created heatmaps are not displayed

Tags: qgis, heat-map, display, kernel-density

I created a few heatmaps based on 2 different shapefiles( point layers). Then I joined the data from the 2 shp files, the joined file looks perfectly fine. I created a view heatmaps based on the new shp file, unfortunately the heatmap layers appear in the layer overview (left side of the screen) without being displayed.

Does anybody know what might be the problem?

Comment: How did you join the two shapefiles?

Comment: I actually did not join them with QGIS but by extracting the relevant columns from the 2 spreadsheets into a 3rd one and then I saved it as a csv file and added it to QGIS.

Comment: Since the tool worked for you with a shapefile and it's not working for you with a CSV, try converting the CSV into a shapefile.

Comment: Thats what I did I saved the csv as a shp but it still does not work. It creats a heatmap file but there is no actual 'heatmap'.

Comment: maybe your CRS got messed up? what happens if you only load the newly created shapefile and you right click on it in the layer overview and click on "zoom to layer" ?